# How to scrape just one text value on one p tag from bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Actually The website has one `<p>` but inside it there are two text values, I just want to scrape one of the texts. website HTML as below:

```
<p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-700 w-1/2" xpath="1">
                        Great Clips

                                                    <br><span class="text-blue-600 font-normal text-sm">Request Info</span>
                                            </p>
```

On HTML above, there are two text values ("Great Clips" & "Request Info")if we target `<p>`. I just want to scrape "Great Clips" not both, how would I do that with `bs4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) with indexing to extract only the first child:

```
soup.p.contents[0].strip()
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p class="text-base font-medium text-gray-700 w-1/2" xpath="1">
                        Great Clips

                                                    <br><span class="text-blue-600 font-normal text-sm">Request Info</span>
                                            </p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.p.contents[0].strip()
```

##### Output

```
Great Clips
```